# Cartesian Product with the Power of an empty set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is $\mathcal{P} (\emptyset) \times \{ 1,2 \} = \emptyset $ or $\mathcal{P} (\emptyset) \times \{ 1,2 \} = \{ (\emptyset,1),(\emptyset,2) \}$?

I can’t figure it out properly, thou I tend towards the latter solution since $\mathcal{P}(\emptyset)$ is not empty but has the empty set in it.

But I am not certain and thankful for every useful answer.

Comment: Do you mean $\mathcal{P}(\emptyset)=\{ \emptyset \}$?

Comment: Yes I mean $\{\emptyset\}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For two sets $A, B$ we have $A \times B = \{(a,b) : a \in A, b \in B\}$. In your case we have the sets $\mathcal{P}(\emptyset) = \{\emptyset\}$ and $\{1,2\}$. Therefore $\mathcal{P}(\emptyset) \times \{1, 2\} = \{(\emptyset, 1), (\emptyset, 2)\}$.

If instead of $\mathcal{P}(\emptyset)$ we looked at $\emptyset$, we would get $\emptyset \times \{1,2\} = \emptyset$.

Comment: Thank you very much, makes sense.